# Query from nested array of arrays of nested dictionary from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following 2 JSON objects in my MongoDB

**JSON - 1:**

```
{
"projectId" : 10003,
"boardId" : 2,
"sprintId" : 3,
"epicId" : 10018,
"storyId" : 10066,
"name" : "Landing Screen",
"status" : "Closed",
"state" : "Closed",
"estimate" : 5,
"estimatedTime" : 0,
"jiraUpdatedDate" :1580208341294,
"changes" : [ 
    {
        "changeId" : "24623",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" :1580208341304,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "status",
                "fieldtype" : "jira",
                "fieldId" : "status",
                "from" : "5",
                "fromString" : "Resolved",
                "to" : "6",
                "toString" : "Closed"
            }
        ],
        "authorIsDeleted" : "true",
        "authorState" : "Inactive",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }, 
    {
        "changeId" : "12755",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" :1576222479010,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "assignee",
                "fieldtype" : "jira",
                "fieldId" : "assignee",
                "from" : "asfasfasfasf",
                "fromString" : "Girish",
                "to" : "bfbasgafasfas",
                "toString" : "Animesh"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "asfsafsafsas",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "false",
        "authorState" : "Active",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "Harish",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }, 
    {
        "changeId" : "10795",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" : 1575028807038,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "Sprint",
                "fieldtype" : "custom",
                "fieldId" : "SprintData",
                "from" : "",
                "fromString" : "",
                "to" : "3",
                "toString" : "Sprint 2"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "bfbasgafasfas",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "true",
        "authorState" : "Inactive",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "Animesh",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }, 
    {
        "changeId" : "10794",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" : 1575028793243,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "summary",
                "fieldtype" : "jira",
                "fieldId" : "summary",
                "from" : null,
                "fromString" : "Landing Screen - Enhancement",
                "to" : null,
                "toString" : "Landing Screen"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "bfbasgafasfas",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "true",
        "authorState" : "Inactive",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "Animesh",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }
],
"type" : "Story",
"typeId" : 10003,
"createdDate" : 1589984431264
}
```

**JSON - 2:**

```
{
"projectId" : 10003,
"boardId" : 2,
"sprintId" : 11,
"epicId" : null,
"storyId" : 12202,
"name" : "MarTech Fixes",
"status" : "In Progress",
"state" : "In Progress",
"estimate" : 2,
"estimatedTime" : 0,
"jiraUpdatedDate" : 1589864759510,
"changes" : [ 
    {
        "changeId" : "51255",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" : 1589864759514,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "Fix Version",
                "fieldtype" : "jira",
                "fieldId" : "fixVersions",
                "from" : null,
                "fromString" : null,
                "to" : "10194",
                "toString" : "1.0.8(4)"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "asfasfasf",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "false",
        "authorState" : "Active",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "ankit",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }, 
    {
        "changeId" : "40223",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" : 1585661512213,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "Sprint",
                "fieldtype" : "custom",
                "fieldId" : "SprintData",
                "from" : "5",
                "fromString" : "Sprint 4",
                "to" : "6",
                "toString" : "Sprint 5"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "bfbasgafasfas",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "true",
        "authorState" : "Inactive",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "Animesh",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }, 
    {
        "changeId" : "40045",
        "changeCreatedDateTime" : 1585636672629,
        "updates" : [ 
            {
                "field" : "Rank",
                "fieldtype" : "custom",
                "fieldId" : "customfield_10019",
                "from" : "",
                "fromString" : "",
                "to" : "",
                "toString" : "Ranked higher"
            }
        ],
        "authorID" : "bfbasgafasfas",
        "authorIsDeleted" : "true",
        "authorState" : "Inactive",
        "authorUsername" : null,
        "authorFullName" : "Animesh",
        "authorShortName" : null
    }
],
"type" : "Task",
"typeId" : 10004,
"createdDate" : 1589984431264
}
```

My MongoDB Query is:

```
db.getCollection('stories').find({
'projectId': 10003, 
'changes.updates.fieldId': 'SprintData', 
'changes.updates.from': '5', 
'type': {'$in': ['Story', 'Task']}
})
```

As a part of the result I should only get **JSON 2** where there is fieldId: SprintData and from:'5' together in one object not different.

What should be my Mongo query?
I have tried using Map Reduce but I don't know more about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **$elemMatch**

> The **$elemMatch** operator matches documents that contain an array
>   field with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y_BqBNX7yx0

```
db.getCollection('stories').find({
  "projectId": 10003,
  "changes.updates": {
    $elemMatch: {
      fieldId: "SprintData",
      from: "5"
    }
  },
  "type": {
    "$in": [
      "Story",
      "Task"
    ]
  }
})
```